# Почему классу видно переменные/функции, если они определены ниже?

Tags: c++, классы

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        if(exist){}
    }
private:
    bool exist = true;
};
```

Почему конструктору видна переменная `exist`? Она же ниже объявлена.

Comment: Согласно стандарту - такой ответ устроит? :)

Comment: ах, со стандартом не поспоришь!

Comment: У компилятор два прохода, сначала исследует все определения в классе и вычисляет размер объекта.

Comment: понял, спасибо )

Comment: Разочаровали - я ожидал вопроса к @AlexGlebe - а почему он так не делает в других случаях?.. :)

Comment: ну так тут можно сделать двойной ответ. Страуструп в своей книге о дизайне с++ как раз написал, почему он так сделал и второе - не хотелось нарушать совместимость с с.